# How do I make Powershell run a batch file and then stay open?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

For example; with the old command prompt it would be:

```
cmd.exe /k mybatchfile.bat
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Drop into a cmd instance (or indeed PowerShell itself) and type this:

```
powershell -?
```

You'll see that powershell.exe has a "-noexit" parameter which tells it not to exit after executing a "startup command".

Answer (score 20):

When running PowerShell.exe just provide the **-NoExit** switch like so:

```
PowerShell -NoExit -File "C:\SomeFolder\SomePowerShellScript.ps1"

PowerShell -NoExit -Command "Write-Host 'This window will stay open.'"
```

Or if you want to run a file and then run a command and have the window stay open, you can do something like this:

```
PowerShell -NoExit "& 'C:\SomeFolder\SomePowerShellScript.ps1'; Write-Host 'This window will stay open.'"
```

The **-Command** parameter is implied if not provided, and here we use the **&** to call the PowerShell script, and the **;** separates the PowerShell commands.

Also, at the bottom of [my blog post](http://blog.danskingdom.com/fix-problem-where-windows-powershell-cannot-run-script-whose-path-contains-spaces/) I show a quick registry change you can make in order to always have PowerShell remain open after executing a script/command, so that you don't need to always explicitly provide the -NoExit switch all the time.

Answer (score -2):

I am sure that you already figure this out but I just post it

```
$CreateDate = (Get-Date -format 'yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss')

$RemoteServerName ="server name"
$process = [WMICLASS]"\\$RemoteServerName\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process"  
$result = $process.Create("C:\path to a script\test.bat") 
$result | out-file -file "C:\some path \Log-$CreatedDate.txt"
```

Comment: Can be test.bat  another ps1 script (c:\path to a script\test.ps1) ? any full sample about it ?